# ¿Cómo insertar cantidades grandes de imágenes en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, estoy desarrollando una tienda online y cada producto tiene un único código y necesito insertar la imágenes con sus respectivas rutas en la base de datos de cada productos.

Cada imagen tiene como nombre FI_IMAGEN<CODIGO_PRODUCTO>.JPG

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo insertar en mysql aproximadamente 2000 imágenes? Estoy trabajando con php.

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el siguiente código puedes recorrer todas las imágenes de un directorio y guardar sus nombres en un array:

```
$pattern = "*.jpg";   
foreach (glob($pattern) as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br>";
}
```

Para guardarlas en tu base de datos, bastaría con insertar dichos nombres, ya que comentabas que tienen el id del producto, por lo que vas a poder acceder fácilmente a ellas. Simplemente tendrías que hacer la consulta SQL correspondiente dentro del bucle `foreach` para ir insertando los nombres de las imágenes en la tabla donde tengas tus productos.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: si me ayudo mucho ahora la duda que tengo es como hago la consulta sql para que me inserte en la base datos las imágenes que le corresponda a cada producto ? tengo la ruta de cada imagen views/app/images/INVENTARIO/FI_IMAGEN0.101.003.531.jpg el codigo del producto es 0.101.003.531 no se si me doy a entender

Answer (score 2):

logre guardar en la base de datos las rutas de las imagenes respectivamente asociado con cada producto con el siguiente codigo:

-cada imagen tenia como nombre FI_IMAGEN"codigo_asociado_al_producto".jpg

```
<?php
$db = new Conexion();
set_time_limit(180);
$pattern = "views/app/images/INVENTARIO/*.jpg";   
foreach (glob($pattern) as $filename) {
    //echo "<br><br> $filename <br>";
    $trozos = spliti ("views/app/images/INVENTARIO/FI_IMAGEN", $filename, 5);
    //echo $trozos[1]."<br/>";
   $trozo = spliti(".jpg", $trozos[1], 4);
   //echo "codigo de la imagen en el directorio: ".$trozo[0]."<br/>";
   $codigoImg = $trozo[0];
   $sql = $db->query("SELECT FI_CODIGO,FI_IMAGEN FROM Sinventario where FI_CODIGO='$codigoImg'");
   $filas =$db->recorrer($sql);
   $FI_CODIGO = $filas['FI_CODIGO'];
   if($FI_CODIGO == $codigoImg){
       $db->query("UPDATE Sinventario SET FI_IMAGEN='$filename' WHERE FI_CODIGO='$FI_CODIGO'");
       echo 'se inserto '.$filename.' en el producto '.$FI_CODIGO.'<br>';
   }else{
       echo 'no concuerdan los codigos';
   }
}
$db->close();
```